# Is their a way to get access to xcode crash logs? Not the crash logs of app that I am developing(From Organizer), but Xcode

Tags: xcode, safari, crash

I want to know it we also have access to mac application crash log, just like we have for iOS. I guess this info will help me figure out why sometimes applications like  Safari/xocde crash occasionally.

Comment: Please describe the logs you're looking for.  What do you expect their contents to be?  What specifically happened that you think would have created them?

Comment: @dg99 well, to answer what happened: I added few constraints to my image and then run my application to see in simulator. Usually if, my simulator should crash, but this time Xcode crashed. I reopened the same project and run it again and again Xcode crashed. Since my app is not crashing I have no logs I can view from Organizer. TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM: I did turn OFF and then ON auto layout and see the simulator, but again that is not a fix to my problem. I want to investigate why my Xcode crashed. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may find here

~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/